# VHDL fullAdder Simulation?

Tags: vhdl

Consider the code below:

```
entity FA is
port(X,Y:in bit;
cin : bit:='0';
sum:out bit;
cout : out bit); --this--
end FA;

architecture Data_flow of FA is
signal S1 , S2 : bit;
begin
S2<=S1 and cin;
S1<=X xor Y;
sum<=S1 xor cin;
cout<=S2 or(X and Y);
end Data_flow;

entity testBench is
end testBench;

architecture BA of testBench is
signal X,Y,cin,sum,cout:bit;
component FA port(X,Y:in bit;
cin:in bit:='0';
sum:out bit;
cout:out bit);
end component;
for all : FA use entity FA(Data_flow);
end for;
begin
EUT:FA port map(X,Y,cin,sum,cout);
X<='0','1' after 4ns;
Y<='0','1' after 2ns,'0' after 4ns,'1' after 6ns;
cin <='0','1' after 1ns,'0' after 2ns,'1' after 3ns,'0' after 4ns,'1'after 5ns,'0'after 6ns;
end BA;
```

I want to simulate this code with VHDL for creating a fullAdder simulation.

I tries it many times, but I can't get my target view.

Comment: You don't provide a [mcve], lacking a clear problem statement it's not verifiable. Besides your tool accepting contiguous abstract literals and identifiers (e.g. 1ns) contrary to IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.3 Lexical elements, separators, and delimiters "At least one separator is required between an identifier or an abstract literal and an adjacent identifier or abstract literal" there are two errors in you configuration specification.  (Lose the `end for;` and entity FA is not visible, use a selected name `for all : FA use entity work.FA(Data_flow);`.  It then simulates (and appears to be correct).

Comment: If you were to provide the error statement output when analyzing  (compiling) your design specification, chances are one of your readers could tell you how to find a solution in your tool or it's documentation.